# Работа с ожиданиями Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не работает программа при комментировании неиспользованного ожидания. Как только убираю комментарии - все работает. В чем ошибка?

```
public class ValidLog {

        WebDriver driver;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            File file = new File(".\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");
        }

        @Test
        public void userLog() {
            System.out.print("Enter ");

            WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id=\"identifierId\"]"));
            login.sendKeys("anykoval1356@gmail.com");
            System.out.print("Input name ");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"identifierNext\"]")).click();
```

//вот это ожидание!

```
      //  WebElement explicitWait1 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
        //        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("password")));

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"password\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("epam1356");

        System.out.print("Input password ");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"passwordNext\"]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"yDmH0d\"]")).click();


        String expectedStr = "Вітаємо, Анна Коваль!";


        WebElement waiting = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"yDmH0d\"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/c-wiz/div/div[4]/div/div/header/h1")));
        WebElement Welcome = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"yDmH0d\"]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/c-wiz/c-wiz/div/div[4]/div/div/header/h1"));
        String strOnPage = Welcome.getText();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Actual result: " + strOnPage);
        System.out.println("Expected result: " + expectedStr);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedStr, strOnPage);
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если выражение занимает 2 строки, комментировать нужно две строки, а не только первую.

Comment: @GennadyZyablitsev Здесь две и закомментировано, просто автор видимо не до конца освоилась с разметкой markdown, которая используется на stackoverflow. Поправил вопрос.

Comment: в закомментированных строках вы просите браузер дождаться загрузки в DOM (то есть, что-бы элемент загрузился) элемента с `id = "password"`. Если без этого ОЖИДАНИЯ код не работает, значит элемент с `id = "password"` не успевает загрузиться до выполнения следующих действий.

Comment: Не подскажете, как нужно написать вместо неиспользованного ожидания? И если бы вы указали ваш комментарий как ответ, я бы смогла его принять